# How to use bitwise shift operator in EL

Tags: jsp, el, bit-shift

I want to calculate a number use el expression.

```
<fmt:formatNumbers value="${num/1024}" pattern="0.00"/>

<fmt:formatNumbers value="${num >> 10}" pattern="0.00" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSP EL doesn't support bitwise operators(only arithmetic, logical and relational operators).Its not implemented in EL. 
If you want to do then, you need to encapsulate the operations within a java class, and expose that to the JSP.
For your reference please look in to given link,
**http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30946&seqNum=4**

** https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html**